# Linked List and inserting a string in alphabetical order

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

I'm writing a program that allows a user to insert, delete, search, and print books. The books must print out in alphabetical order. When I'm inserting books, it works just fine but it does not put them in the right order and it will crash. Here is my code for the insert function.

```
void BookList::Insert(Book* nBook)
    {
        string name;
        int quant;
        double p;
        cout << "Enter the title of the book." << endl;
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, name);
        cout << "Enter the number of quanities of this book." << endl;
        cin >> quant;
        cout << "Enter the price of this book." << endl;
        cin.ignore();
        cin >> p;
        nBook->title = name;
        nBook->quantity = quant;
        nBook->price = p;
        nBook->next = nullptr;
        //cout << "test" << endl;
        //If the current book is lexicographically smallest.

        if (first == nullptr) {
            first = nBook;
            cout << first->title << endl;
        }
        else if (nBook->title <= first->title)
        {
            cout << "new first" << endl;
            nBook->next = first;
            first = nBook;
        }

        else
        {
            cout << first->title << endl;
            //if current book is lexicographically small between two books.
            Book* prevPtr = first;
            while (prevPtr != nullptr)
            {
                cout << "Looking at: " << prevPtr->title << endl;
                if (prevPtr->title > nBook->title)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    prevPtr = prevPtr->next;
                }
            }

            nBook->next = prevPtr->next;
            prevPtr->next = nBook;

        }
    }
```

P.S. This is in C++
Thank you

Comment: *it works just fine but it does not put them in the right order and it will crash* -- So it doesn't "work fine".  Also, [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Jenah, make sure you take the time to learn how to debug your program and be able to step through it and watch what happens as the code executes each line. This is a critical skill as you learn how to write code (and solve problems with your code).

Comment: In this case, I suggest you focus on `while (prevPtr != nullptr)` and the lines after the `while` (e.g. `nBook->next = prevPtr->next;`), and think about (or watch what happens) when `prevPtr == nullptr`.

Comment: Think about what happens when your new book is after all the existing books. Then `prevPtr` equals `nullptr` but you execute the code `nBook->next = prevPtr->next;`

Answer (score 0):

Just because something doesn't show an error at compile doesn't mean it works fine. 
Why are you using cin.ignore() with no parameters? What is the single character you are trying to ignore? You realize cin >> (someint or somedouble) already ignores whitespace and return characters, right?

More of your code is needed for context, but it seems like you're trying to fill the information for the new book into a "nBook" node before you actually initialize a new "nBook" node.

Also, I suggest not putting that output at the end in the method. If your method is for adding a new book to your linklist, just use it to add it. Put those outputs in a separate method, or in the calling method. (or maybe you just put those in for debugging purposes, in which case nvm)
Just my 0.02

Comment: Alright, I went through all my code and debugged it. It appears that for some reason first is updating somewhere in the code to be set equal to the last title I enter in, ultimately causing it to not work. Would you be willing to look at my updated code and see what i'm missing?

Comment: Can you add your struct definition for clarity? Or class? Whatever you used to define 'Book'....

Comment: also need to know how you are calling this function….
Are you using 'new' to declare a pointer to a new nBook before you call it or are you passing in an existing nBook member.
If you're passing in an existing nBook member, the way I see it one of two things is happening:
1. You are overwriting an existing nBook
or
2. You had an extra (empty) nBook declared prior that is just sitting there, which is a bad practice. Only initialize it if it is needed.